# "Export to vector file failed. Error: Feature write errors" in QGIS 2.18 but works in 2.4

Tags: qgis, error, qgis-2.18

I'm having a problem with QGIS 2.18.7 'Las Palmas' which did not occur with version 2.4 (the standard with my OS - Debian Linux).

I have a *.kml file containing the boundaries of UK parliamentary constituencies. It loads into QGIS as a vector layer fine, but if I then try to save  as *.shp, I get the following:

===================

> Export to vector file failed. Error: Feature write errors: Feature
>   geometry not imported (OGR error: Field URI of width 255 truncated to
>   254.) Feature geometry not imported (OGR error: Field URI of width 255 truncated to 254.) Feature geometry not imported (OGR error: Field URI
>   of width 255 truncated to 254.) Feature geometry not imported (OGR
>   error: Field URI of width 255 truncated to 254.) Feature geometry not
>   imported (OGR error: Field URI of width 255 truncated to 254.) Only
>   645 of 650 features written.

================

This doesn't happen with QGIS 2.4.

Why is this happening?

Comment: could download the OS boundary-line data as a shapefile